# Force close when new fragment with async task is launched

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a button that loads a new fragment but it is force closing with this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.BPTopTastes.onCreateView(BPTopTastes.java:29)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the button that loads the new fragment is this:

```
public class Discover extends Fragment {
    Fragment Fragment_one;
    Fragment Fragment_two;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_discover, container, false);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

        //add button onclick fo top beers
        Button bt = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.discoverBeers);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do whatever stuff you wanna do here
                FragmentManager man=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction tran=man.beginTransaction();
                Fragment_one=new BPTopBeers();
                tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
                tran.addToBackStack(null);
                tran.commit();
            }
        });

        //todo: add button onclick fo top tastes
        Button bt2 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.discoverTaste);
        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do whatever stuff you wanna do here
                FragmentManager man=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction tran=man.beginTransaction();
                Fragment_two=new BPTopTastes();
                tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_two);//tran.
                tran.addToBackStack(null);
                tran.commit();
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //todo: change to discover layout
        return v;

    }
```

the fragment that is being launched is:

```
public class BPTopTastes extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taste_statistics_layout, container, false);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

        String title = "Top Tastes on Beer Portfolio";
        TextView topTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.topTasteTitle);
        topTitle.setText(title);


        //construct url
        String url = "myURL";


        //async task goes here
        new GetTasteStatisticsJSON(getActivity()).execute(url);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;

    }



}
```

and the async task which is being called is:

```
public class GetTasteStatisticsJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    public GetTasteStatisticsJSON(Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Getting  tastes");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);


            //acces listview
            ListView lv = (ListView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.yourTasteStatistics);

            //make array list for beer
            final List<TasteInfo> tasteList = new ArrayList<TasteInfo>();



            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                String style = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("taste");
                String rate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rate");

                int count = i + 1;

                style = count + ". " + style;

                Log.d("brewery stats", style);

                //create object
                TasteInfo tempTaste = new TasteInfo(style, rate);

                //add to arraylist
                tasteList.add(tempTaste);


                //add items to listview
                TasteInfoAdapter adapter1 = new TasteInfoAdapter(c ,R.layout.brewer_stats_listview, tasteList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);


                //set up clicks
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        TasteInfo o=(TasteInfo)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                        String tempTaste = o.taste;



                        //todo: load taste page fragment
                        //Intent myIntent = new Intent(c, TastePage.class);
                       // myIntent.putExtra("taste", tempTaste);
                        //c.startActivity(myIntent);


                    }
                });








            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

I am a bit confused cause I have another button in the same fragment that launches a new fragment in a similar way just fine...

Comment: The code looks fine, although are you sure that the shared preferences are populated prior to the call? That may be what is causing the null pointer

Comment: 100% sure its populated. I just added the whole code for where my button is. Could the first button before it be interfering with the second button? The first button works fine...

Comment: where is line 29 of `BPTopTastes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed my mistake after combing through my code. I have the wrong id here in this line:

```
 TextView topTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.topTasteTitle);
```

so it could not find that, to set the title.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the BPTopTastes layout is inflating correctly, and hence topTitle is not null when you call the setText() method on it.

Does it work when you remove the async task ?

The Eclipse debugger can be set to halt on exception which might give you some pointers.

Comment: I dont think its inflating correctly, its crashing before I new screen is shown. Not even getting my loading dialogue. Will check what happens when I comment out the async. BRB